# keyword search Java

Tags: java, search, keyword

I am trying to search through a sentence and return it if it contains the specific "keyword" but atm it only work if the search is exactly the same as the message, so if the sentence is "hello my name is ben" then the search wont work with only "ben" or "hello" but I would have to use "hello my name is ben" for it to display, How would I get this to work. Thanks

```
public ArrayList<Message> getMessageByKeyword(String messageBody){
    ArrayList<Message> keyword = new ArrayList<>();

    for( Message p : this.myMessages)
        if( p.getMessageBody() == messageBody)
        {
            keyword.add( p );
        }

    return keyword;      
}
```

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: I am no trying to compare if the strings are the same, Im just trying to see if  the string im searching for is inside the sentence, im not trying to check if they are the same

Comment: Then perhaps you'll want to use the `String#contains(...)` method. But one thing is for certain -- don't use `==`.

Comment: Have you looked at the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) yet? That probably has all you need to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Ill look at it

Comment: I got it working using the String#contains(...) thanks again